# Pattern for Asynchronous Web-api method with registered callback

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, callback

I'm looking at how to create a .net web-api method which is asynchronous i.e:
- It runs the actual task as a background task but returns a status straightaway 
- It is also passed callback information which it calls back when background task is complete.

I understand the theory and have noticed articles around Request/Acknowledge however im struggling to find a well document .net version of the pattern which achieves the above and doesn't cause multi-threading issues on my web-api? I don't want to do anything bespoke because surely this is a common .net implementation?

Comment: You can use http://hangfire.io/ if you want to execute background tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok seems like there nothing magical in terms of solution:

public HttpResponseMessage SomePostMethod(Request request)
{

Validate(request);

QueueForBackGroundAsync(request);

return HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
}